# Java script array returun object object error

Tags: javascript, rally

Javascript returns object object error while executing this code.As i am new to javascript,i am not able to identify the specific issue.Also the name of the user story is not properly aligned wiht the Userstory id.Looking for help.Thanks in advance.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>UserStoryWithPredecessors</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

                launch: function() {
                    Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                        model: 'UserStory',
                        fetch:                
                   ['Iteration','FormattedID','Name','Predecessors','PredecessorID','Project','ScheduleState'],
                         filters: [
                         {
                          property: 'Iteration.Name',
                          operator: '=',
                          value: 'RT4 Iteration #4'
                       }
                     ],
                         autoLoad: true,


                        listeners: {
                            load: this._onDataLoaded,
                            scope: this
                        }
                    });
                },                

                _onDataLoaded: function(store, data) {
                    var records = [];
                    Ext.Array.each(data, function(record) {
                        //Perform custom actions with the data here
                        //Calculations, etc.

                        var myPredecessors = record.get('Predecessors');

                        var predecessorData = "";
                        var predecessorCreationDate = "";
                        var predecessorState = "";
                        var predecessorProject = "";
                        var predecessorID = "";
                        var predecessorName = "";

                        // Loop through and process Predecessor data
                        for (var i=0; i<myPredecessors.length; i++) {
                            thisPredecessor = myPredecessors[i];
                            thisPredecessorFormattedID = thisPredecessor["FormattedID"];
                            thisPredecessorName = thisPredecessor["Name"];
                            thisPredecessorScheduleState=thisPredecessor["ScheduleState"];
                            thisPredecessorProject= thisPredecessor["Project"];

                            // Post-pend updated data to value for array
                           // predecessorData += thisPredecessorFormattedID + ": " + 
          thisPredecessorName + "<br>"                            
                            predecessorID += thisPredecessorFormattedID + "<br>";
                            predecessorName += thisPredecessorName + "<br>";                            
                            predecessorState += thisPredecessorScheduleState + "<br>";
                            predecessorProject += thisPredecessorProject + "<br>";  
                        }  


                        records.push({
                            FormattedID: record.get('FormattedID'),
                            Name: record.get('Name'),
                            Iteration:  
              (record.get('Iteration')&&record.get('Iteration')._refObjectName) || '',
                            PredecessorID : predecessorID,
                            PredecessorName : predecessorName,
                            PredecessorState: predecessorState,
                            PredecessorProject: predecessorProject, 
                           });
                    });

                    this.add({
                        xtype: 'rallygrid',
                        store: Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                            data: records,
                            pageSize: 20
                        }),
                        columnCfgs: [
                            {
                                text: 'Iteration', dataIndex: 'Iteration', width: '100px'
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'FormattedID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', width: '100px'
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name', width: '400px'
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'PredecessorID', dataIndex: 'PredecessorID', width: '100px'
                            },
                            {
                              text: 'PredecessorName', dataIndex: 'PredecessorName', width: 
                '200px'
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'Project', dataIndex: 'PredecessorProject', width: '200px'
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'State', dataIndex: 'PredecessorState', width: '400px'
                            }
                             //,
                            //{
                            //    text: 'Predecessor Creation Date(s)', dataIndex:  
                'PredecessorCreationDate', width: '200px'
                           // }
                        ]
                    });
                }
            });
            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name: 'UserStoryWithPredecessors'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .app {
             /* Add app styles here */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

i have found an answer the question my self.I did small modification in the code and it works. 
thisPredecessorProject= thisPredecessor["Project"]._refObjectName;

I need to Print this sheet in to a Report.Looking for yours assistance.Thanks in advance.